# Replace method's Body with Body of another method using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, reflection.emit, mono.cecil

With `Mono.Cecil` it looks quite simple when we can just set the `Body` of the target `MethodDefinition` to the `Body` of the source `MethodDefinition`. For simple methods, that works OK. But for some methods whereas a custom type is used (such as to init a new object), it won't work (with an exception thrown at the time writing the assembly back).

Here is my code:

```
//in current app
public class Form1 {
  public string Test(){
   return "Modified Test";
  }
}
//in another assembly
public class Target {
  public string Test(){
    return "Test";
  }
}

//the copying code, this works for the above pair of methods
//the context here is of course in the current app
var targetAsm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("target_path");
var mr1 = targetAsm.MainModule.Import(typeof(Form1).GetMethod("Test"));
var targetType = targetAsm.MainModule.Types.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "Target");
var m2 = targetType.Methods.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "Test");
var m1 = mr1.Resolve();
var m1IL = m1.Body.GetILProcessor();

foreach(var i in m1.Body.Instructions.ToList()){
   var ci = i;
   if(i.Operand is MethodReference){
      var mref = i.Operand as MethodReference;
      ci = m1IL.Create(i.OpCode, targetType.Module.Import(mref));
   }
   else if(i.Operand is TypeReference){
      var tref = i.Operand as TypeReference;
      ci = m1IL.Create(i.OpCode, targetType.Module.Import(tref));
   }
   if(ci != i){
       m1IL.Replace(i, ci);
   }
}
//here the source Body should have its Instructions set imported fine
//so we just need to set its Body to the target's Body
m2.Body = m1.Body;
//finally write to another output assembly
targetAsm.Write("modified_target_path");
```

The code above was not referenced from anywhere, I just tried it myself and found out it works for simple cases (such as for the 2 methods `Test` I posted above). But if the source method (defined in the current app) contains some Type reference (such as some constructor init ...), like this:

```
public class Form1 {
  public string Test(){
   var u = new Uri("SomeUri");
   return u.AbsolutePath;
  }
}
```

Then it will fail at the time writing the assembly back. The exception thrown is `ArgumentException` with the following message:

> "Member 'System.Uri' is declared in another module and needs to be imported"

In fact I've encountered a similar message before but it's for method calls like (`string.Concat`). And that's why I've tried importing the `MethodReference` (you can see the `if` inside the `foreach` loop in the code I posted). And really that worked for that case.

But this case is different, I don't know how to import the used/referenced types (in this case it is `System.Uri`) correctly. As I know the result of `Import` should be used, for `MethodReference` you can see that the result is used to replace the `Operand` for each `Instruction`. But for Type reference in this case I totally have no idea on how.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to replace the body with a call to the new method?

Comment: @JeroenMostert here the source `Test` method is just a simple one, in fact it could be any complicated code (containing dozens of lines ...). So if we convert those code manually to `Instructions` everytime, it would be hard and not interesting at all. I would like to use an existing method to replace code of another one defined in another assembly. I really think this is feasiblle with Mono.Cecil.

Comment: No, my point is -- the method body you want has already been compiled correctly (including type and assembly references and the whole hoopla). Rather than trying to transplant it into a new body, why not replace the `Source.Test` method body with a call to `Target.Test`? (If the existence of a separate assembly is a problem, ILMerge them first.) This would work irrespective of how complicated source or target are.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I don't understand what you mean, what I want to replace is the `Target.Test` but just its `Body`. So when the `Target` class (after modified by saving as a new assembly) is used elsewhere (not in my current app), the `Test` method will do what I want (by defining a fake method `Test` - as well as the source method - in the current app).

Comment: The scenario here is I don't have access to code for the assembly that  defines `Target` class, I can just use `Mono.Cecil` to replace the `Test`'s Body to what I define in another method (the source method).

Comment: I think you have to use http://reflexil.net/ and .Net Reflector to done it.

Comment: @moien thank you, I've just tried playing around with that tool, it looks fairly promising. But looks like currently it's still limited and unfortunately that I could not solve my problem with it. I've tried the feature "Replace all with code" and I can type code directly in an editor, but the `System.Uri` is still not able to be referenced. I understand that the `System.dll` is missing, although it should be included by default. This may be because of Mono.Cecil working in a fairly independent way with the existing .NET Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All my code posted in my question is fine BUT not enough. Actually the exception message:

> "Member 'System.Uri' is declared in another module and needs to be imported"

complains about the `VariableDefinition`'s `VariableType`. I just import the instructions but not the Variables (which are just referenced exactly from the source `MethodBody`). So the solution is we need to import the variables in the same way as well (and maybe import the `ExceptionHandlers` as well because an `ExceptionHandler` has `CatchType` which should be imported).
Here is just the similar code to import `VariableDefinition`:

```
var vars = m1.Body.Variables.ToList();
m1.Body.Variables.Clear();
foreach(var v in vars){
   var nv = new VariableDefinition(v.Name, targetType.Module.Import(v.VariableType));
   m1.Body.Variables.Add(nv);
}
```